# What does Oracle SQLCODE ORA-00942 signify?

Tags: oracle

I am very sorry if I am asking a very basic question, but I Googled for this and found no useful info. Could you please explain what the Oracle SQLCODE `ORA-00942` stands for?

Comment: Was it ORA-00942 or SQL*Loader-00942? They are different error codes.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/ulus.htm#SQL_Loader-00100):

> **SQL*Loader-00942:** partition string not part of table string
>
> **Cause:** the specified partition is not part of the specified table
>
> **Action:** None

Comment: @user3289248:- You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

`SQLCODE` is Oracle variable that is visible throughout a session and its value is modified whenever a statement is executed in oracle. If there is no error after execution of sql statement, its value is set to 0 by Oracle. For all other error status, a negetive value is stored that ranges from -20000 to -1.

If you write `SQLCODE=-00942`, you are basically checking if value stored in `SQLCODE` is -00942 (i.e. ORA-00942: table or view does not exist) after executing a particular statement. Oracle throws exception if `SQLCODE` returned is negative and that we can handle in exception part based on `SQLCODE` returned.

Answer (score 1):

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.

This does **not** necessarily mean that the table or view in question does not exist! This error is **normally** due to the user trying to access a resource to which they don't have the proper privileges - it's not usually because the table doesn't in fact exist, it's just that the user doesn't have the privileges to access it in the way that they wish to!

Login as sysadmin and verify that it exists - if it does, `GRANT SELECT` (`UPDATE`... whatever) to your user and then it should start working.

An example is shown [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php):

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON suppliers TO smithj;
```

If you find that you are doing this frequently, you should look into the Oracle roles facility which allows you to effectively perform multiple privilege assignements in one statement to groups of users.

i.e. you can assign the HR department access to the `salary` table but exclude other departments - create a HR role and `GRANT SELECT` on that table to anyone who has the HR role - much easier than fiddling about `GRANT`ing table access to individuals on an ad-hoc basis! It's explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm#DBSEG004).

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL*Loader-00942: partition string not part of table string
    Cause: the specified partition is not part of the specified table
    Action: None
```

from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/ulus.htm#SQL_Loader-00942